# Enable Dictionary Object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

When I initiate a dictionary object in Excel VBA, I found out two methods:

1. Use `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` (no "Microsoft Scripting Runtime");
2. Turn on the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" first, then use `Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary`

Both of them work on my machine. I am wondering is there any difference between these two methods?

Comment: The difference is 1: `Late` or 2: `Early` binding method. They have pros and Cons. For #1, other users machine does not require to add the Reference to use your VBA, but there are no IntelliSense while you code. For #2, VBE IntelliSense may pick up methods and properties of the object, but requires the Reference to be added on all other machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference I know is the first one uses `Late bind` and the second one uses `Early bind`. The difference between the two is explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115/).

Early bind has advantages. One of which is you can use `Intellisense` to guide you on the available properties of the bound object that you can use in coding. Also, it is said that it is faster in terms of performance. You can also use built-in constant as is. No need to check it's equivalent value. This is discussed [here](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html).

Late bind has advantages as well specially if you bound objects that have different versions. This reduces the risk of runtime errors due to version incompatibility (also mentioned in the 1st link).

As for me, I always use Early bind during development so I can utilize `Intellisense`. If there is a need to convert to Late bind, I'll do it later after I or the customer have done robust testing.

**Additional:**

When you use Early bind `Don't Use Auto-Instancing Object Variables` as discussed by CPearson in his post [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx). Below is the excerpt from his blog.

> For object type variables, it is possible to include the New keyword in the Dim statement. Doing so create what is called an auto-instancing variable. Again, while this may seem convenient, it should be avoided. Contrary to what some programmers may believe, the object isn't created when the variable declaration is processed. Instead, the object is created when it is first encountered in the code. This means that, first, you have limited control when an object is created. Second, it means that you cannot test whether an object is Nothing, a common test within code and a common testing and diagnostic technique.

So a better way to set your variable is:

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: No valid arguments by  Chip Pearson: ' limited control when an object is created'. Creating it at the start seems to me 100% control. The testing of a Dictionary as 'Nothing' or not sopesn't make any sense. No plausable reason to do that in a  procedure.  With the 'auto instantiating' MS introduced a very handsome and lean improvement in the VBA language. For more on dictionaries see www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html